# Unable to use Hive Plugin in Flutter

Tags: android, database, flutter, dart, hive

flutter pub get give error

```
Running "flutter pub get" in practice...                        
Because every version of flutter_test from sdk depends on quiver 2.1.3 and practice depends on quiver 2.1.0, flutter_test from sdk is forbidden.

So, because practice depends on flutter_test any from sdk, version solving failed.
pub get failed (1; So, because practice depends on flutter_test any from sdk, version solving failed.)
exit code 1
```

version I am using

```
[√] Flutter (Channel dev, v1.18.0, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18363.752], locale en-IN)
    • Flutter version 1.18.0 at C:\src\flutter
    • Framework revision 8f7327f83a (3 weeks ago), 2020-04-06 22:11:01 -0400
    • Engine revision 49891e0653
    • Dart version 2.8.0 (build 2.8.0-dev.20.0 1210d27678)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both `flutter_test` and `practice` depends on `quiver` package, but each with different version.
You can force using the latest version of `quiver` which should allow you to pass the `flutter pub get` with no errors:

```
dependency_overrides:
  quiver: 2.1.3
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need to add one plugin.

```
dependency_overrides:
  dartx: ^0.3.0
```

Comment: Still same problem

Comment: ```dependencies:
  hive: ^1.4.1+1
  hive_flutter: ^0.3.0+2

dev_dependencies:
  hive_generator: ^0.7.0+2
  build_runner: ^1.9.0```
this type of your pubspec.ymal file? @AlokKumar

Comment: yes, dependencies: hive: ^1.4.1+1 hive_flutter: ^0.3.0+2 dev_dependencies: hive_generator: ^0.7.0+2 build_runner: ^1.9.0 . Every plugin is upto date